# Magento - Create a SALE product collection taking into account special_price & promo price rules

Tags: magento, collections, product

I need a product collection consisting of products where the special_price is current and/or they match any promotional price rule.  I'm doing something similar elsewhere in my site at the moment using getFinalPrice() but I can't add that as a filter, can I?

I've got two separate blocks of code that individually more or less do what I want and I guess they should fit together somehow:

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(9);
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
$productIdsArray = $rule->getMatchingProductIds(); 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $productIdsArray));
```

and

```
$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('y'));
$tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left');
```

The code filtering promo rules requires a promo rule id but I'm really interested in ALL promo rules rather than one specific one.

Can anyone help me fit these together into one please?

Thanks,

~gpcola

Update 10/11/11:

Ok so here is what I've ended up with:

```
// get catalogue price rule promotion product collection  
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$rules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')
                        ->getResourceCollection()
                        ->addWebsiteFilter(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId());
foreach($rules as $rule) {
    $promoids =  array_merge($promoids, $rule->getMatchingProductIds());
}

$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$pricecollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$pricecollection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

// get special price product collection  
$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('y'));
$tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);
$pricecollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                        ->addMinimalPrice()
                        ->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($pricecollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($pricecollection);

$pricecollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
                                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                                ), 'left')
;

// merge the collections
$merged_ids = array_merge($pricecollection->getAllIds(), $promoids);
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $merged_ids)
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1);

return $this->_productCollection;
```

But this is returning no products... I have around 1000 products that match one promo price rule or another so I know that's incorrect.  Any ideas?

oh by the way if I print_r($this->_productCollection) I get the following:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection Object
```

(
    [_flatEnabled:protected] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

```
[_productWebsiteTable:protected] => catalog_product_website
[_productCategoryTable:protected] => catalog_category_product
[_addUrlRewrite:protected] => 
[_urlRewriteCategory:protected] => 
[_addMinimalPrice:protected] => 
[_addFinalPrice:protected] => 
[_allIdsCache:protected] => 
[_addTaxPercents:protected] => 
[_productLimitationFilters:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_productCountSelect:protected] => 
[_isWebsiteFilter:protected] => 
[_priceDataFieldFilters:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_map:protected] => Array
    (
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [price] => price_index.price
                [final_price] => price_index.final_price
                [min_price] => price_index.min_price
                [max_price] => price_index.max_price
                [tier_price] => price_index.tier_price
                [special_price] => price_index.special_price
            )

    )

[_storeId:protected] => 1
[_itemsById:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_staticFields:protected] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => entity_id
        [type_id] => type_id
        [attribute_set_id] => attribute_set_id
    )

[_entity:protected] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Flat Object
    (
        [_storeId:protected] => 1
        [_resources:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource Object
            (
                [_connectionTypes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [pdo_mysql] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql Object
                            (
                                [_name:protected] => 
                                [_entityClass:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Entity_Table
                            )

                    )

                [_connections:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [core_read] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object
                            (
                                [_transactionLevel:protected] => 0
                                [_connectionFlagsSet:protected] => 1
                                [_ddlCache:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
...
```

Does that look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fetch all rules, use the collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')
        ->getResourceCollection();
```

then apply the `addWebsiteFilter($websiteIds)` method on it. Then you'll have to loop through it and get the matching products ids (as you're doing in your code), and you can merge them with something like:

```
$merged_ids = array_merge($collection1->getAllIds(), $collection2->getAllIds());
```

This last line (the merging stuff) should work also to merge the catalogrules id's with the special prices ones.

HTH

Comment: Hi OSdave - I've applied what you suggested (see my update above) but I'm getting no products returned and I know I should be getting around 1000.  Could you take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @gpcola at the end of your code, change `->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $merged_ids)` by `->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$merged_ids)`